# How does TBB gets "Provided bridges"?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bridge, obfsproxy

I used "use provided bridges" option for obfs3 in TBB 3.6.
When I got TBB 3.6.2, I didn't copy over torrc from old directory, I thought it might get new set of "provided bridges", but when I opened and read TBB 3.6.2's torrc file, it has the same set of obfs3 bridges as in the TBB 3.6's torrc.

So now I wish to know how TBB gets its list of "provided bridges"? Is it added with the downloaded TBB itself? Then, everyone will be able to see the bridges from sourcecode and add it to their tor nodes blocklist?

Answer (score 1):

The list of provided bridges is shipped with the Tor Browser itself (see [bridge_prefs.js](https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git/blob/HEAD:/Bundle-Data/PTConfigs/bridge_prefs.js) in the source).

The list itself is assembled by the Tor Browser and pluggable transport teams with addresses of bridges run by long time members of the Tor community.